# Capitalization and periods in LaTeX section headings

Tags: sectioning, capitalization

I’m fairly new to LaTeX but love it. I am putting together the backbone of my dissertation in Report class. I am bound to APA style for headings. Using the Titlesec package I’ve got the headings very close, and here is my question: The level 2 heading (section) has major words capitalized, bold font flush left. The third level (subsection) is only first word capitalized, indented, and ends with a period. Is it worth trying (or even possible)  to format the sections in Titlesec to handle the capitalization and periods, or should I just type the headings in that way every time and not worry about it?
Thanks for your time

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976737/capitalization-and-periods-in-latex-section-headings?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

The following might work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifmtarg
\let\oldsubsection\subsection% Keep "old" definition of \subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsection}[2][]{% First letter capatalized and end in period.
  \@ifmtarg{#1}%
    {\oldsubsection{\MakeUppercase #2.}}% \subsection[..]{...}
    {\oldsubsection[#1]{\MakeUppercase #2.}}% \subsection{...}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{FIRST SECTION}%
\subsection{first subsection} Here is some dummy text.
\subsection{Second subsection} Here is some more dummy text.
\end{document}
```

The renewed `\subsection` command makes a choice depending on whether you supply a different (shorter) ToC entry or not. Regardless, `\MakeUppercase` converts the first character to uppercase, and appends a `.` at the end of the subsection title.

[image: Subsection formatted with first letter capitalized and ending in period.]

Note that the new `\subsection` definition will **always** append the subsection title with a period, regardless of whether you add one or not. However, the capitalization is less rigid, as you can see from my example.

Even though the example provided is typeset in the `article` documentclass, it would work similarly for the `report` documentclass.